# Insert from one table to another and then delete from the table

Tags: sql

How do you insert from one table into another and then delete from the first table after insert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need two queries for this.

The first query is to copy records from the first table,

```
INSERT INTO tableTwo(col1, col2,...,colN)
SELECT  col1, col2,...,colN
FROM    tableOne
```

The second one is to delete the records from the frist table,

```
DELETE FROM tableOne
```

In order to have one call, you can wrap those queries in a `STORED PROCEDURE`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procName()
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO tableTwo(col1, col2,...,colN)
    SELECT  col1, col2,...,colN
    FROM    tableOne;

    DELETE FROM tableOne;

END
```

and call the procedure

```
CALL procName();
```

---

*The syntax of the Stored procedure above works on `MySQL`. What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `SQL Server`? `MySQL`? `Oracle`? `DB2`? etc.. so i can update the answer.*

Answer (score 2):

How about a single call to move the records?

```
DELETE FROM tableOne
OUTPUT col1, col2,..., colN
INTO tableTwo
```